# How to remove elements added using the before() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing an alert-style div when a user selects an option from a form and clicks the add to cart link. I am using the jQuery .before() method to add the text-value of the users form selection to the div.

What I need help with is two-fold:

If the user does not close the div and then proceeds to make another selection, how can I replace the element added using .before() with the new selection?

Also, if the user does close the div, how can I 'reset' it, so that if they were to make another selection (say on another page) the div would properly display their latest selection.

Here is the working code:

(Div being called)

```
<div class="alert-box success">
    <span id="alert-copy"><?php echo ' tin of ' . $current_page["product_name"] . ' '; ?> added to cart  |  <a href="#" class="alert-btn-cart">View Cart</a></span>
    <a href="" class="close">&times;</a>
</div>
```

(Current jQuery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("div.alert-box").hide(); 
    $("input.button.small.radius.submit").click(function(){
    $("#alert-copy").before('<span>' + $('select option:selected').html().split("-")[0] + '</span>');
    $("div.alert-box").show("normal");
</script>
```

For what its worth, I am using Zurbs Foundation (V3) for the alert divs.

Also, you can view the current construct of the select forms / add-to-cart links via the clients live site (which is currently using a 'Colorbox', but will be moving to the style described above as soon as I can get this figured out).

http://campbellssweets.com/shop/popcorn/product.php?subject=Bacon+and+Cheddar+Popcorn

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.alert-box").hide(); 
$("input.button.small.radius.submit").click(function(){
var content = $('<span>' + $('select option:selected').html().split("-")[0] + '</span>');
$("#alert-copy").before(content);
$("div.alert-box").show("normal");
$("#remove").click(function(){ content.remove(); });
```

Then remove it by clicking `#remove`.

Comment: So that code does add the users additional selection, but it fails to remove the previous (3.5 Gallon 2 Gallon tin of Bacon and Cheddar Popcorn added to cart). Also, I just noticed that if the alert box is closed manually via the <a href="" class="close">&times;</a>, it fails to reopen when the add-to-cart link is clicked again.